# Word Automation using WIN32OLE

Tags: ruby, ms-word, win32ole

I am trying to insert an image (jpg) in to a word document and the Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture does not seem to be supported by win32old or I am doing something wrong.  Has anyone had any luck inserting images.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by calling the Document.InlineShapes.AddPicture() method.

The following example inserts an image into the active document, before the second sentence.

```
    require 'win32ole'

    word = WIN32OLE.connect('Word.Application')
    doc = word.ActiveDocument

    image = 'C:\MyImage.jpg'
    range = doc.Sentences(2)

    params = { 'FileName' => image, 'LinkToFile' => false, 
               'SaveWithDocument' => true, 'Range' => range }

    pic = doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture( params )
```

Documentation on the AddPicture() method can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb148763.aspx).

Additional details on automating Word with Ruby can be found [here](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/search/label/word).

This is the answer by David Mullet and can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316162/insert-image-in-doc-using-win32ole-library-of-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

Running on WinXP, Ruby 1.8.6, Word 2002/XP SP3, I recorded macros and translated them, as far as I could understand them, into this:

```
require 'win32ole'

begin
  word = WIN32OLE::new('Word.Application')   # create winole Object
  doc = word.Documents.Add
  word.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture "C:\\pictures\\some_picture.jpg", false, true
  word.ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\\docs\\"
  doc.SaveAs "doc_with_pic.doc"
  word.Quit
rescue Exception => e
  puts e
  word.Quit
ensure
  word.Quit unless word.nil?
end
```

It seems to work. Any use?